# Good practice for modifing vuex on initial app load

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuex, vue-router

**Introduction:**

Currently the application has multiple modules that store data, for example:

- profile

- models

- products

- etc

... later components under the different routes reuse and modify store data.

**The problem:** 

When the application is initially loaded (no matter what route, or component) it's needed that certain logic has to be executed in order to set the needed state of store.

**Simple example can be:**

Depending on the user's age in the profile:

1. Find a certain model in models

2. And update profile data with the values from model

There are methods like `created()` or `mounted()` during component creation, so it made me think about some sort of representational container under the parent route. But I wonder maybe there are different sort of hooks to be added on the initial application load.

Comment: I think what you are looking for are renderless components where you can put your module loading logic and then wrap your routes within? I use  the created hook to load or reuse  vuex modules

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You usually feed your initial data into the store from another (persistent) data storage. This can be LocalStorage or an external source (an REST API for instance).

One way of doing this is too `postpone` app creation until the store is populated and then proceed with app init.

You init code in `main.js` will look something similar to this

```
import store from './store'

someAsyncTask()
.then( () => {
 new Vue({
   el: '#app',
   router,
   store,
   template: '<App/>',
   components: { App }
 })
})
```

This means that the user needs to wait until everything is loaded so presenting a static preloader (usually added in index.html) is a good option.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem ended up very obvious, but initially escaped my mind. Since the `App` (root component) is being passed to the `Vue` instance, all logic required for manipulating can be actually executed there during `created` or `mounted` methods.

However if you actually rely on the AJAX calls to be resolved before initialising the app the Radu Dita approach should be taken into the consideration.